# How to preserve a object through multiple pages

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

I have an ArrayList of objects and I use them as follow:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{BookReview.books}" var="book" >
    <li>
        <h:commandLink value="#{book.bookName}" action="detail" />
    </li>
</ui:repeat>
```

in the detail page I show the book's comments, and I have a form to register a new comment:

```
<h:form>
    Name:<h:inputText value="#{Comment.author}" />
    Rate:<h:inputText value="#{Comment.rate}" />
    Text:<h:inputText value="#{Comment.comment}" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{book.addComment(Comment)}" value="Add Comment" />
</h:form>
```

My problem is that `book` isn't preserved until the next Request and `#{book.addComment(Comment)}` results in `Target Unreachable, identifier 'book' resolved to null`.

I have tried annotate the book as `RequestScoped`, didn't work, then I've modified to `ViewScoped`, didn't work either, then I tried to use a `<inputHidden >` to keep the object around, but it just uses a `.toString()` and I can't reuse the object.

I don't want to use session to store the object because I need it only once, and I don't think I want to use a converter because `Book` has a `ArrayList` of comments (also I think it is to cumbersome and complicated)

Answer (score 1):

Put your `BookReview` bean to the `session` scope (or, if you're on JSF-2.0 - then let it have the `view` scope).

Comment: `BookReview` is ApplicationScoped, `Book` and `Comment` currently don't have a scope defined, so I supose they have a DependentScope or something like. `BookReview` has an ArrayList of Books and `Book` has an ArrayList of Comments

Answer (score 1):

You've got to keep a handle of the current book somewhere and relate the new comment with it.

Create a new bean, `BookDetail`.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BookDetail {
    private Book book;
    private Comment comment = new Comment();

    public String addComment() {
        book.getComments().add(comment);
        // You need to persist book here if necessary.
        return "list";
    }

    // Add/generate getters/setters the usual way.
}
```

Set the selected book as follows (could be done nicer if you were using an `UIData` component like `h:dataTable` or `t:dataList` instead of `ui:repeat`):

```
<h:commandLink value="#{book.name}" action="detail">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bookDetail.book}" value="#{book}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Rewrite the detail form as follows:

```
<h:form>
    Name:<h:inputText value="#{bookDetail.comment.author}" />
    Rate:<h:inputText value="#{bookDetail.comment.rate}" />
    Text:<h:inputText value="#{bookDetail.comment.comment}" />
    <h:commandButton action="#{bookDetail.addComment}" value="Add Comment" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Apparently `getComments()` returned `null` instead of empty list.

Comment: f:setPropertyActionListener didn't work for me, I did some testing and find out that the Book object was not being set on the BookDetails object, I have no idea why. 
But I managed to use t:saveState :D